# flutter catching errors of nested async methods

Tags: dart, flutter, futuretask

I have this method.

```
asyncFunction1() async {
  Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction){
    var first = await transaction.something;
    var second = await secondInside();
  });
}
```

Now I want to call this method, and catch every error that happens inside. How would I propagate errors so that

`try {asyncFunction1()}
catch(e){}`

catches all errors that happened inside runTransaction?

Comment: Do you see a different behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Your inner function misses an `async` to be able to use `await`. If you add it, you can use `try`/`catch`

```
asyncFunction1() {
  Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
    try {
      var first = await transaction.something;
      var second = await secondInside();
    } catch(e) {
      ...
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can you also give an example of how to catch this error in the future instance of the above async function?thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You just need to await the call and wrap it with `try`/`catch`.

Comment: Apologize for the confusion. What I mean is if you have assigned this to a variable: Future<void> asyncFunction = asyncFunction1();
When we add asyncFunction.catchError((error){}), can this catch the exception that already caught in the above block?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I still don't think I understand the question but `catchError` is the canonical way of handling exceptions of async code, `try`/`catch` can only be used with `async`/`await`.

Comment: The main reason for me is to trying to understand the relationship between future and async function.Maybe my example is bit confusing. Please let me give another one:
Future<void> asyncFunction async{ try{...}catch{} }      
Future<void> asyncInstance = asyncFunction;     
asyncInstance.catchError((error){});
Hmm, the code is a bit hard to read, maybe i should create a question for it.